# Triple Quotation Marks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, quotation-marks

In Python, there are these triple quotation marks ('''), for  multiple line strings, which is very useful. Is there any way to do this in javascript?

Comment: You can use the backticks instead of regular quotation mark to add multiline strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the template literal. Encase your strings in  backticks (`)

For your reference, check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: thanks, but i can't acept an answer just yet.. sorry it says that you can accept an answer in 4 minutes

Comment: Thank you for accepting it. Glad I could help. Happy coding!